# D3.extent() does not give the right range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3. I just started to create a scatterplot from a csv file. However, I find that d3.extent gives wrong ranges as described below. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

The data (in csv format created in Python) has the following ranges:

```
In [56]: min(x), max(x)
Out[56]: (-10, 14)

In [57]: min(y), max(y)
Out[57]: (-5, 1)
```

However, when I use d3.extent, I get the following ranges:

[image]

The whole code is found on: [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/rohitx/e262b30de54906912971) and here's the snippet:

```
        // Get the data
        d3.csv("hip_fake_data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
        x_value = d.x_hip;
        y_value = d.y_hip;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.x_hip;}));
        y.domain([d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y_hip; }), -5]);

console.log(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.x_hip;}))
console.log(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.y_hip;}))
```

Comment: convert string value to numeric value when you are reading the csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d3.csv("hip_fake_data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    x_value = +d.x_hip; // convert to number
    y_value = +d.y_hip;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It still does not work. I get Array[2]0: "-1"1: "9"length: 2__proto__: Array[0] and Array[2]0: "-1"1: "1"length: 2__proto__: Array[0]. Which again is the same I got earlier.

Comment: could you create a plnkr so i can help you on it?